# Odd ng-model Behavior with nested checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

Ok, so here is a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/p7eJFTdsk9CFXwEIXZyb of the behavior that I am experiencing. I have tried to use the same ng-model on all levels but that also displays odd behavior and this is the closest I have gotten to what I am actually trying to accomplish.

I would like the toplevel checkbox to work like the sublist1 checkboxes.

Steps to create unwanted behavior:

1. click top level checkbox for item 1
2. click top level checkbox for item 1 again, so far works as expected.
3. click sub level item 2.1 checkbox this works. However the Top Level Item 1 checkbox will no longer change the item 2.1 checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each ng-repeat creates a new scope, once a deep scope is manipulated to have it's own properties, it will no longer inherit from higher level scope.

This is expected.
Check out a question on my profile regarding `scope` and `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I am not sure we are quite talking about the same thing, I am not trying to update a higher level scope, its the lower level scope that stops working, I understand what you mean about it creating a new scope when its altered, but it should be inheriting its scope from the top level still shouldn't it? According to your question reference, the model should be inheriting from $parent in the normal $digest.

Comment: We are talking about the same thing. It will only inherit the higher level scope AS LONG as the local scope doesn't have a property with the same name. Once you manually check a box in the sub scope, it creates its own property. That scope will only see the local property now, not the property it inherited from above. The local scope will now take precedence over `ng-checked="TopLevelGroup"`

Comment: Hmm.. You are right in that scope was part of the problem, and this link provided a lot of insight into that. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#wiki-ngRepeat

Buts its not the solution to the problem here, even with knowing about prototype inheritance it would not fix the issue on its own, I have to rework the entire model to use 2 dimensional array to point to the proper model for each nesting. Doing this would fix the issue without worrying about inheritance. otherwise I would never be able to nest more than 2 levels deep.

Comment: But since I cannot vote yet, all I can do is mark it as the answer because it at least pointed me in the direction I needed to go.